# Microsoft Remote Desktop types 'c's and 'b's when I use media keys? Can it not?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, remote-desktop, media-player, media-keys

I really like the Win10 Remote Desktop, but when I hit the volume-down and volume-up keys while in the terminal session, it types out lowercase c and b, respectively. Mute is 'd'? It also prevents the music keys from doing what they're supposed to.

Is there a way to have these keys specifically bypass the capture, like NoMachine did?

Comment: Activating the "Use keyboard commands with my local PC only" function lets the media keys work, but Volume up/down still types b & c in addition to changing volume...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to go over. Type of keyboard, and version of RDP are you using.
I have a k350 logitech and using RDP protocol 8.1 (prior versions had issues).

Currently the special keys do work on RDP.

Comment: Issue happens with my Dell laptop's built in keyboard, and my logitech wireless keyboard, and the media buttons on my HEADPHONES.

The special keys "work" in that they increase and decrease the volume, they just also type things.